# Kohana 3.2 PHP5 controller action not invoking

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

Newbie here trying to maintain a PHP website for some charity organization, but cannot get a controller action to invoke:

Under */application/classes/controller*,

I have a file called *history.php*.   Content of this file looks like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_History extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_index()
    {   
        $this->response->body('hello, world!');     
    }       
}
```

When I go to mydomain.com/history, I get error 404 indicating The requested URL /history was not found on this server.

Boostrap.php has the following default routes defined:

```
Route::set('welcome-message1', 'directors-welcome-message')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'messageDirector',
    ));

Route::set('welcome-message2', 'directoress-welcome-message')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'messageDirectoress',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

/application/logs/2012/06 contains no errors.

Can someone please give me a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a kohana error or an apache (web server) error? Do you have htaccess enabled? Try `/index.php/history`.

Comment: Looks like a kohana error because I am getting the requested URL /history was not found on this server.  mydomain.com/index.php takes me to home page.  mydomain.com/index.php/history gives me same error.   Did not run into htaccess in the docs but what is this and how do I enable?  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was missing .htaccess.